# Error on Nested If-Statement

Tags: java, if-statement, conditional-statements

I tried to create a program using a nested `if-statement` in Java. But I'm confused because I'm getting an error on the `else if statement` in Eclipse.

```
import java.io.*;

public class Sem3 {    
    public static void main (String [] args) throws IOException
    {
        InputStreamReader inStream = new InputStreamReader (System.in);
        BufferedReader stdin = new BufferedReader (inStream);
        int x ;
        String str;            
        {
            System.out.print("Please Input An Integer :");
            str = stdin.readLine(); 
            x = Integer.parseInt(str);
            if (x == 10)
                System.out.print("Your Integer Is Equal To 10");
            else if (x == 11)
                System.out.print("Your Integer Is Equal To 11");
            else 
                System.out.print("LOSER");
        }                
    }
}
```

My question is, why can't I do another `if-statement` after `else if` or `if` condition, but I can do another `if statement` after the `else` condition?

Comment: And the error is....?

Comment: Do you mean "why can't I place *more than one* statement following an "else if" statement? The answer is that you can, but you have to mark the statements as a block by enclosing them within curly braces { }. if statements only support a single following statement by default in the absence of a curly brace marked block.

Comment: Also, the curly bracket after **String str;** shouldn't be there.

Comment: What? Where do you want to put the other 'if' statement? What error are you seeing? Why did you bracket out that section after 'str' was declared?

Comment: He will get error if he removes { after String str;  he needs to also remove } after else

Comment: you need to separate blocks that belong to an `if` or an `else` in `{ }`

Comment: What is the other if statement that you aren't able to do?

Comment: @SamTebbs33 It is perfectly legal code... unnecessary, but legal.

Comment: @Edie as a side note, you should consider switching to using `Scanner` instead of `InputStreamReader` and `BufferedReader`. Like: `Scanner stdin = new Scanner(System.in); stdin.readLine();`

Comment: @SnakeDoc My lect not allow me to use scanner.. So , I need to use BufferedReader for IO program. For you guys.. thanks for explaination.. you guys help me so much. :')

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your if-else-elseif block needs to take the following form, with curly brackets surrounding each block:

```
    if (x == 10){
            System.out.print("Your Integer Is Equal To 10");
            /*more conditions here...
              if(condition){

              }else if(condition2){
              }
              */
    }else if (x == 11){
            System.out.print("Your Integer Is Equal To 11");
    }else {
            System.out.print("LOSER");
```

Comment: Thanks for your explaination.. Now i already figure out my mistake.. I owe you sir. Well , thank you so much! :) @SamTebbs33

Answer (score 1):

What you have here is called a `Single Selection If Statement` which will only execute the next line of code, if the conditional evaluates to `TRUE`.

Like:

```
if (someConditional)
    // do this if true
// this, here,  will always execute
```

Your issues is you have a dangling `else if`, which is not attached to anything as far as the compiler is concerned.

What you are after is an `If Statement Block`, which looks like:

```
if (something) {
   // do stuff
} else if (somethingElse) {
    // do stuff
} else if (somethingEvenElse) {
    // do stuff
} else {
    // do stuff
}
```

The block will execute any number of statements within the `{ }`.

Comment: Thank you sir.. I will make your comment as my reference.

Answer (score 0):

First of all curly bracket("{ }") block not require after String str where you place your if/else condition; So try to remove that bracket set { }.
According to your question "My question is, why can't I do another if-statement after else if or if condition".

You can do if or else if statement after the if condition.

For example (just a syntax not any specific code) - it will compile

```
 public void test() {

        int i =0 ;
        int j=1;
        if(i==1)
        {
           System.out.println("print--"+i); // goes more logic or conditions here
        }
        else if (j==1)
        {
               System.out.println("print--"+j); // goes more logic or conditions here

        }
        if(i==0)
        {
               System.out.println("print--"+i); // goes more logic or conditions here
        }
        else
        {
          // goes more logic or conditions here
        }
        if(true)
        {
          // goes more logic or conditions here

        }
   }
```

Comment: Yuupp.. I got it sir... Thank you so much... my bad. I appreciated your explanation.. thank you sir.